# Colocando um vetor em ordem decresente

Tags: java

Preciso criar um vetor de tamanho N mas ele tem que esta ordenado decrescente só que quando eu faço o codigo sempre da 0.

```
public int[] vetor_dec (int n) { 
    int[]vetor = new int[n];
    for(int i=n;i>vetor.length;i--) {
        int aux=0;
        vetor[aux]=i;
        aux++; 
    } 
    return vetor;
}
```

Teria como me dizer o que esta errado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olhei rápidamente aqui seu `int aux=0;` esta dentro do `For`, esta alimentando seu vetor sempre na posição 0 !

Answer (score 4):

Os problemas no seu código são os seguintes:

1. Você nunca vai entrar nesse loop:

   ```
   for(int i=n;i>vetor.length;i--) {
   ```

   Ao iniciar, `i` vale `n`, que é igual a `vetor.length`; quando a condição for testada, dará `false` de cara, de modo que ele vai retornar o vetor inalterado.

   E como em Java um vetor é sempre iniciado com tudo zero (ou `null`, se for um vetor de referências) então é isso que você vai obter.

   Uma solução é percorrer de `n` até `1`:

   ```
   for(int i=n;i>0;i--) {
   ```
2. O `aux` está sendo definido dentro do corpo do loop

   ```
   for(int i=n;i>vetor.length;i--) {
       int aux=0;
   ```

   Isso significa que, mesmo que seu primeiro problema seja resolvido, ele sempre será zero. Isso faria com que você atribuísse a posição zero do seu vetor, várias vezes (uma sobrescrevendo a outra). O resultado seria algo do tipo:

   ```
   {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
   ```

   Para resolver isso, é só mover o `aux` para fora do loop, de modo que ele preserve seu valor (incrementado por você) entre uma iteração e outra:

   ```
   int aux=0;
   for(int i=n;i>vetor.length;i--) {
   ```

Código completo:

```
int[]vetor = new int[n];
int aux=0;
for(int i=n;i>0;i--) {
    vetor[aux]=i;
    aux++; 
} 
return vetor;
```

Nota: estou assumindo que você quer valores de `1` a `n`. Se quer outro intervalo - por exemplo de `0` a `n-1` - ajuste a condição do seu `for` de acordo.

Answer (score 3):

Muda o seu **for** e tira a variável **aux** do loop.
Deixa o código assim:

```
public int[] vetor_dec (int n) { 
    int[]vetor = new int[n];
    for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--) {
        vetor[i]=i+1; 
    } 
    return vetor;
}
```